# How to Scan an artifact on nexus before deploying the artifact

Tags: security, nexus, artifact

I have a pipeline where I checkout code from git, build artifacts and publish the artifacts to Nexus.

Now before I deploy the artifacts, I want to scan them for any vulnerability. How I can achieve it. Are there some tools available.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is basically the use of Nexus Lifecycle and Firewall tools.  They scan items as they enter your repository manager.

I suggest reading more about them here:

- https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-lifecycle
- https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-firewall

Note neither of them are free services, they require a license.

Comment: Aside FYI on naming, "Nexus" is actually the suite of tools by Sonatype, despite the label in SO that indicates it's the repository manager (here it is).  But to explain why they are also "Nexus" =)

Answer (score 0):

Nexus is to late. You should scan the artefacts in Jenkins when you have both the sources and binaries to your disposal. There should be tutorials how to do something like Jenkins-Sonar Qube integration.

Imagine following. You have scanned an artefact and you see vulnerabilities. What are you doing then? Are you willing to remove it from repository? Imagine the problems you will generate this way. And the dev team will say, that they did not see the results of your scan so they could not act upon it and now this artefact is going to be deployed...

Comment: You are right but the use case is like this: I own the code, but the environment is with client. Even if i scan in advance using sonar cube, still client would want to scan it.So before deploying the artifacts scan is required due to client's policy.

Answer (score 0):

After RnD, I found a possible solutions. Answer provided by @joedragons is also useful. I guess jforg xray is also good a solution.

https://jfrog.com/xray/

**JFrog Xray** is a continuous security and universal artifact analysis tool, **providing multilayer analysis of containers and software artifacts for vulnerabilities**, license compliance, and quality assurance. Deep recursive scanning provides insight into your components graph and shows the impact that any issue has on all your software artifacts.